# Basic Code (first time coding) errors (visual studio 2015 for desktop express)

Tags: c#

```
        Console.WriteLine("Type a number, Any number!");
        ConsoleKeyInfo KeyInfo = Console.ReadKey();

        if (KeyInfo.KeyChar -- 'a')
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thats not a number, Knock it off!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Did you press {0}", KeyInfo.KeyChar.ToString());
    }
}
```

I'm getting the below errors for the above code, how can I fix these?

```
CS1026 ) expected
CS1002 ; expected
CS0200 Property or Indexer 'ConsoleKeyInfo.KeyChar' Cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
CS1513 } expected
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ConsoleKeyInfo.KeyChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx) *Gets the Unicode character represented by the current `ConsoleKeyInfo` object*. So it's a read only property and it means that you can't modify the value of this property.

By looking your code, it seems that you want to check for the character `a` in your `if` condition. So for that just use the [comparison operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx)(equality operator) `==` like this

```
if (KeyInfo.KeyChar == 'a')
```